# When is it Necessary to Use Deregistration Functions Returned by $on and $watch methods?

Tags: angularjs

Is it recommended to always hang on to the $on method, as in

```
var dereg = $scope.$on(...)
```

And later

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() { dereg(); });
```

Or is this only needed for certain situations?  Same question for $watch

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you should only use `$destroy` event when your app may have memory leak issues or zombie events.

`$destroy` is useful when you pass some of the directive's variables to another directive or controller, and after the element gets removed, yo want to remove it from the reference.

For instance, you may want to use `$destory` when your directive creates event handlers on global `DOM` elements and the element with the directive gets removed.

let's say this is a linking function inside a directive:

```
function myEventListener(){console.log('scroll!');}
$window.bind('mousewheel',myEventListener);
scope.$on('$destroy',function(){$window.unbind(myEventListener)});
```

If you don't unbind your event listener, then after the element with the directive gets removed, you will still have `scroll!` messages when you scroll.